# Are there infinitely many primes of the form $3^p-4$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

My question is the same as you saw:

> Are there infinitely many primes of the form $3^p-4$, when $p$ prime?

I'm a complete novice in this type of questions with few or no theoretical background. Um, so I could only try it by brute-force for all primes $p<15,000$. Then, I found something interesting: it seems not so plausible, because $p$ with $3^p-4$ prime gets rapidly rare, as $p$ increases.

The complete list when $p<15,000$ is: $\{2,3,5,31,37,41,53,73,101,557\}$. The largest integer $n<15,000$ with $3^n-4$ prime I found is $4823=7\times 13\times 53$.

It seems quite hard, so I just hope I could find some references or survey articles. At least, is there a verified infinite sequence of primes in a set $\{a^p-b^q:$ $p,q$ primes$\}$ for some fixed primes $a,b$?

Comment: I expect that this is going to be very difficult. With $a=2$, $b=1$, we have Mersenne primes, which infinity of such primes is unknown.

Comment: Ah, I didn't see that $b$ has to be prime. But, still it looks difficult.

Comment: This is probably an open question.

Comment: OEIS entry [A058959](https://oeis.org/A058959).

Comment: @Raymond Manzoni: thanks :) at least both 3^52057-4 and 52057 are primes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not known in general whether or not there are infinitely many primes of the form $a^p+b$. Some results are known for $a=2$, e.g., see [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5323/infinitely-many-primes-of-the-form-2nc-as-n-varies). 
Even for polynomials of degree $\ge 2$ the question is not known. There we have   the so-called [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture).

Comment: These are not polynomials...

Comment: ...and therefore Bunyakovsky does not apply.

Comment: I am sorry. I was thinking of $a^{2k}+1=(a^k)^2+1=x^2+1$ for the polynomial $x^2+1$.